PixiJS character animated sprite not updating when getting reassigned
I am trying to update an animated sprite object and i have instantiated them like this:
characterMovement["walk_down"] = 
  PIXI.AnimatedSprite.fromFrames(animations["walk_down/walk_down"]);
characterMovement["walk_up"] =
  PIXI.AnimatedSprite.fromFrames(animations["walk_up/walk_up"]);
characterMovement["walk_left"] =
  PIXI.AnimatedSprite.fromFrames(animations["walk_left/walk_left"]);
characterMovement["walk_right"] =
  PIXI.AnimatedSprite.fromFrames(animations["walk_right/walk_right"]);

I then assign it like this:
character = characterMovement["walk_down"];
Then I have some code that dependign on what key is pressed the animated sprite object should change like this:
if (keys['87'] && character.y > 0) {
    character= characterMovement["walk_up"];

however nothing happens when i reassign it.
I have tried just reassigning the textures like this: character.textures = characterMovement["walk_up"].textures; and that works but doesnt cycle through the animations.

You could try by updating the texture inside a ticker loop, as follows:
const keys = {};

  window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    keys[event.key] = true;
  });

  window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    keys[event.key] = false;
  });

  app.ticker.add(() => {
    if (keys["ArrowUp"]) {
      character.texture = walkUpTexture;
      character.y -= 2;
    }
    if (keys["ArrowDown"]) {
      character.texture = walkUpTexture;
      character.y += 2;
    }
    if (keys["ArrowLeft"]) {
      character.texture = walkDownTexture;
      character.x -= 2;
    }
    if (keys["ArrowRight"]) {
      character.texture = walkDownTexture;
      character.x += 2;
    }

    character.rotation += 0.01;
  });

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-jones-nyp48k
